# Is author talking about past or future possibility with "If I sit… a stranger could"

Tags: modal-verbs

> If I sit in the middle, a stranger could sit next to me

In the context, "If I sit in the middle" is present tense. How to find out if author talking about past possibility or future possibility?

Comment: Welcome to ELL and thanks for your question. Please take a few minutes to review our [**tour**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [**Help Center**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages. We hope you will ask more questions.

Comment: We use the modal _could_ (+verb) to talk about something that is possible, but not certain, in the future. To talk about something that was possible in the past, we use _could have._ Thus, _"If I **had sat** in the middle, a stranger **could have sat** next to me."_

Comment: To amplify @P.E.Dant 's comment, you can start with the first clause, "If I sit in the middle". Since that is present tense, yet a conditional, you are not sitting in the middle yet.  Therefor the sentence either relates to the future, or something you are pondering in general.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is *current* or *future* possibility.

*Past* possibility might be

> If I ***(had)* sat** in the middle, a stranger **might/could have sat** next to me.